# Protractor open new window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Lets say I am working on a chat application, where a user (X) can login to the application and send a message to another user (Y).

I am now trying to automate the test to send and receive messages, with the following steps:

```
1. X Logs in with his username/password.
2. Selects Y from a list and sends a "Test Message" to Y.
3. X signs out.
4. Y logs in with his username/password.
5. Checks if he has received the message from X.
6. Y replies to X with "Reply to Test Message".
7. Y signs out.
8. X logs in, and checks if he got the reply.
```

If I were to do this manually, I would just open two windows (one of them in incognito), login as X on one and as Y on the other and verify the results.

So, few questions: 
1. Does protractor allow a way in which a new window can be opened without any clicking anywhere? Just a function to spawn a new window programmatically?
2. Is it possible to have these windows not share the session of the user (kinda like incognito)?

Answer (score 5):

The following works fine for me.

```
browser.executeScript('window.open()').then(function () {
     browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            var secondWindow = handles[1];
            browser.switchTo().window(secondWindow).then(function () {
                return browser.get(newPageToOpen);
            });
     });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could open a new incognito by sending the CTRL+SHIFT+N key combo:

```
browser.actions()
       .sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.SHIFT ,"n"))
       .perform();
```

then use window handles, and switch between windows

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
  browser.switchTo.window(handles[1]); // 0 or 1 to switch between the 2 open windows
});
```

after you switched between the windows, all your next methods will be for the active window.
if it works for you in incognito, should work here too.

Comment: Hi, While the answer seems to be right, I am afraid it won't work on a mac as Key.COMMAND seems to be not supported by webdriver. Any other alternatives please?

Comment: hmmm, did you try it on a mac? because according to [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/enum_webdriver_Key.html): Key.COMMAND is indeed supported

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in this way:

```
let _2ndBrowser = browser.forkNewInstance();
let url = 'https://google.com';

browser.get(url);
_2ndBrowser.get(url);
browser.element(by.xpath(...)).click();
_2ndBrowser.element(by.xpath(...)).click();
```

works fine.

If you are using PageObject you can set browser as constructor argument. and set in in **new**:

```
function LoginPage(browserContext) {
  this.setUserName = function(userName){ 
    return browserContext.element(/*locator*/).sendKeys(userName)
  }
}

it('set login name', function() {
  let _2ndBrowser = browser.forkNewInstance();
  let user1LoginPage = new LoginPage(browser);
  let user2LoginPage = new LoginPage(_2ndBrowser);

  user1LoginPage.setUserName('alice');
  user2LoginPage.setUserName('bob');
})
```

PROFIT =)

Answer (score -1):

For everyone who is looking for **typescript** solution.

[vrachlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3630378/vrachlin) code with small changes will work just fine:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(handles => {
   browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]); // 0 or 1 to switch between the 2 open windows
});
```